# Trigger to Insert data in a table before updating a column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that inserts a timestamp to table `log` before I update column within a table. For example if I update table `hits` column `number` from 1 to 2. I want the time recorded before the column was updated, but this record of the time the update was done must only be when `hits.number` is updated. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if old.number <> new.number then insert.

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON hits
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.number <> OLD.number THEN
    ->         INSERT ...
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;//
```